# Haskell, typesig Map.Map, LYAH

Tags: haskell, types, declaration

I don't quite get the Map.Map part. I understand that when I import qualified as Map, I need to prefix addressing that as 'Map.' but whereas that is normally followed by a function (eg. 'lookup'), here two types are used.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map 
phonebook :: Map.Map String String
```

I get that phonebook takes a String and a String, but is Map.Map strictly there to indicate it is an association list, or is there more to it? And why are the arrows omitted?

Comment: Types, functions, etc. are all elements that ship with a module. So you here use the `Map` type from the `Data.Map` module.

Comment: You could certainly implement `Map` as a function from a key type to a value type (`newtype Map a b = Map (a -> b)`), but that's an implementation detail that wouldn't be exposed by the type itself.

Answer (score 6):

`Data.Map` exports a type called `Map`:

```
data Map k a
```

whose definition is hidden. The qualified import means that to refer to that type, you need to prefix it with the name you stuck after `as`. So `Map.Map` is just the name of the finite map type constructor.

```
Map.Map String String
```

is simply the type of finite maps from strings to strings.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to show an unqualified use too?  If you `import Data.Map` then you could instead write `Map String String`, i.e., you can drop the qualified name prefixing the type.

Comment: Or if you do `import qualified Data.Map as M`, it's `M.Map`.

Answer (score 2):

`phonebook` is of type `Map String String` (if you were to import with `import Data.Map (Map)`). That is, it a mapping of `Strings` to `Strings`.

More generally, the `Map` type constructor can be written as `Map key value` where `key` and `value` can be thought of as type arguments *yet to be applied*. Hence we say `Map` has the *kind* `* -> * -> *` where the stars themselves are concrete types.

So in...

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map 

phonebook :: Map.Map String String   -- passing "arguments" to Map here
phonebook = undefined
```

You're `phonebook` has the kind `*`.

Comment: `Map` has the kind `* -> * -> *` not `* -> *`

Comment: Oops my bad, fixed.